# Array of objects vs Object of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, json, performance, maintainability

The issue is to decide the trade offs between the following notations:

**JSON based**:

```
"users": {
    "id1": {
        "id": "id1",
        "firstname": "firstname1",
        "lastname": "lastname1"
    },
    "id2": {
        "id": "id2",
        "firstaame": "firstname2",
        "lastname": "lastname2"
    }
}
```

**Array Based**:

```
users: [
    {
        "id": "id",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    },
    {
        "id": "id",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    }
]
```

Relating to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882985/array-of-objects-vs-nested-object) post on the same issue, I have decided (on front end) to use the JSON object notation instead of an array of objects as it suits my requirements, provides better performance, and results in less code in the browser.

But the problem is that the list itself is not static. By this I mean the list is being generated i.e. fetched/stored from DB (NoSQL) and created for new entries through a Java API on the server. I am not able to decide on which notation I should use at the back end (which eventually will also affect the UI too).

Any thoughts/suggestions about performance, maintainability or scalability is appreciated.

Comment: How are you comparing both this approach. In JSON based you are putting values as id and in array based you are putting it as array. What is your requirement?

Comment: In Javascript I can get the object using the `id`(for JSON), but in case of array I have to loop through the whole list and match the `id` property of each object, which can be a bottleneck in case of large data sets. So JSON works fine for me in browser but I am not sure is creating the same structure by Java will have any performance issues.

Comment: How will your JSON approach support multiple user entries?

Comment: @NamanGala: Please take a look at the updated JSON sample.

Comment: In the backend, you just need a `Map<Long, User>`. But I would simply use an array (in JSON) and a List (on the backend): usually, the order matters. And a Map won't give you any order. If you're so worried about performance, transform the array into a map in JavaScript.

Comment: Note that JSON always has one root element, which can either be an object `{}` or an array `[]`. So the terminology `Json based` vs `Array based` should actually be `(Json)-Object based` vs. `(Json)-Array based`

Comment: If performance is of concern, consider also: [JSON Compression: Transpose & Binary](http://mainroach.blogspot.ca/2013/08/json-compression-transpose-binary.html)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a totally subjective question. There might be many other points, but let me point out a few below:

**JSON based approach:**
If I am not wrong then this will be implemented using `Map` on server side.

**Advantage:** In JavaScript you can directly use `users.id1`, `users.id2`, i.e. no need of iteration

**Disadvantage:** On the client side, somehow you will need the ids to be  present in your JSON, i.e. either hard coding them or using some dynamic approach which will tell you which id is present in your JSON.

---

**Array Based approach:** If I am not wrong then this will be implemented using `Array`/`List` on server side.

**Advantage:**

1. On client side, you can directly iterate through array, without
   worrying in advance about which id is present inside it i.e. no hard
   coding.
2. As pointed out by **@JBNizet**, the array based approach will maintain the order.

**Disadvantage:** If you want to fetch single id then you will need to iterate through the array.

Generally we don't send much information on the client side, so array based approach will not create any problem. And **transforming an array into a map is possible on both sides (server and client)** if you want an id based approach.

Comment: These are nice pints but I am more concerned about what happens at the server.

Comment: The hard-code part is not really a problem. You can also iterate an object `for(key in obj)` and you can make the key values configurable. But I doubt that this would even be neccessary.

Comment: @maja: Actually I don't have to iterate over the key of objects. I already have the keys(which are not hard coded).

Comment: As pointed out by @JBNizet, If order is important then array based approach is required.

Comment: @maja, in that case, both the approach are same, you are iterating in both the cases.

Comment: @NamanGala Yes. If the client doesn't know which users it will receive (which is usually the case), it has to iterate in both cases. Since Arrays are actually special Objects in JavaScript, there won't be any significant performance overhead on the client side though.

Comment: @maja, you are right, and we should not worry about client side performance either.

Comment: @NamanGala That's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer^^. For the client side it's completly irrelevant how the data is presented. Only the network overhead is slightly bigger in case of objects, especially if the id's are very long. What really matters are the semantics.

Answer (score 7):

On the server side, Arrays are stored as simple Lists: `ArrayList<Content>`, while Objects are either stored as maps: `HashMap<String, Content>` or, mostly, as Java Objects.

In order to convert Java Entities to and from JSON, you can take a look at the [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) project which does all that for you.

I wouldn't worry about any performance differences between those two variants. It's more important to have an understandable, semantic API, so you should base your decision on the business case rather than performance.

Looking at your example, I think an `Array` is the better approach, since you want to return a list of users which are all equal. Sending the id twice makes no sense imho and increases the amount of data that has to be transmitted.

Furthermore, since `Arrays` are much simpler to store and to iterate in Java, they should also provide better performance than Objects.

**Some general differences:**

- Arrays preserve the order
- Arrays can contain duplicate entries
- Objects often have a bigger storage/network overhead
- Arrays are faster to iterate (on the server side)

Answer (score 4):

Along with all the above technical differences, I think there is a fundamental difference in the purpose and meaning of an `Object` and an `Array`.

1. The properties of an object **DESCRIBE/DEFINE** the object whereas
2. The elements of an array do **NOT DESCRIBE/DEFINE** the array, on the contrary, the array defines what its contents are.
   Do note - I am not talking about technical aspects. You can have any combinations technically but semantically each has its own purpose.

- For example a card holder. Each card does **NOT DESCRIBE/DEFINE** the cardholder. But the cardholder does define its purpose - that it holds only cards.
- An Object is used to represent an entity and its properties **DESCRIBE/DEFINE** the entity. Take the same example of a Card. A card has properties like color, number which **DESCRIBE/DEFINE** what the card is.

For your above example:

1. Each object which represents a person **is defined by the properties** `id`, `firstName`, and `lastName`.
2. A list of these persons cannot be an object of objects because **each id does not describe the object of objects**. So

```js
"users":[
    {
        "id": "id",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    },
    {
        "id": "id",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    }
]
```

is a better representation than

```js
"users": {
    "id1": {
        "id": "id1",
        "firstname": "firstname1",
        "lastname": "lastname1"
    },
    "id2": {
        "id": "id2",
        "firstaame": "firstname2",
        "lastname": "lastname2"
    }
}
```

even though technically you can use either.
I hope I was able to convey (put into words) my thinking in the proper manner.

Comment: Can I know why the negative voting? I think stackoverflow should make it compulsory to comment for negative voting so that people are aware what their mistake it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `object[property]` [notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to access or set properties in an object in JavaScript.

Go with *array based* approach at the backend, and convert the array to a map (*JSON based* as you refer to it) in the front end.

```
var list = [{id: "id1", value: "One"}, {id: "id2", value: "Two"}]
var map = {};
list.forEach(function (item) { map[item.id] = item });
map.get("id1")
```

If your list changes, you can get the new list from backend and update your map in UI.

This way your backend is faster to respond as it does not have to convert list to a map. Your front end will do a O(n) iteration *once* over the list to convert it to a map. But that is a small price compared to O(n) you will pay every time you search on a list.

If you will be doing get by id predominantly on your data at the back end go with *JSON Based* at the backend itself (you can use `LinkedHashMap` to preserve order).

Answer (score 1):

One big disadvantage of your first "JSON based" notation that comes to mind is that some frameworks will have problems with (de)serialization of this. For example the DataContractSerializer (C# .NET) will expect the fields `id1` and `id2` to be defined (hardcoded) in the class of your objects `users`. I'm not sure if this applies to some Java frameworks, too. Maybe the framework will you use can deserialze it as a HashMap instead.

Altogether I'd find the array notation much more intuitive to work with when it comes to iteration etc.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches have their pros and cons and depends on what is it that you are looking at.

The array approach is easy to serialize and is more 'framework' friendly (you can add beans to a list and serialize the list and you are done). This allows, for example, a web-container to return the response without requiring any customization. This is likely to be supported out-of-the-box by most frameworks.

On the other hand, the object based approach is more difficult to generate (in relative terms) but its easier to lookup given the key is known.

So for ease of implementation (by producer), go for the array based approach. For ease of use (consumed by clients) go for object based approach.